# Comparing .diagsessions files

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.15, I'm using the Performance tool to measure performance degradation that occurred in a new version of our program (a huge, mainly C program).

Usually I run both the old version and the newer version on the same test, and manually going through the performance tool file to see the difference.

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically compare between two .diagsession files - something similar to a diff command.

I am aware of this [How to: Compare performance data files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/profiling/how-to-compare-performance-data-files?view=vs-2017)
, however they are talking about .vsp files.

Is this even possible on Visual Studio?